# Why do flags revert to red in Lion Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

In Lion Mail, in (IMAP) accounts other than iCloud/MobileMe, flags that I set to colors other than red revert to red over time.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? What is the soruce of the problem? Is it a bug in Mail, or is it a problem at the server?

Comment: I am unable to replicate. How long is "over time"? I set several flags of various colors on several IMAP accounts on October 20 when you asked the question, and they are all still red.

Comment: @Daniel: Several days is usually enough for some, but not all, flags to "revert". Quitting and relaunching Mail seems to revert a bit more quickly. If your flags are indeed attached to messages stored on the server, and if they're stable for a week or more, then you probably don't have my problem, which suggests it's a mail server issue.

Comment: @Daniel: FWIW, the servers in question are Network Solutions hosted. I'd be interested whether anyone else with NS hosted IMAP is having this issue.

Comment: All mine are hosted at Google (gmail, google apps for your domain). It sounds like this might not be an Apple Mail problem at all, but rather an ISP issue.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?
I am running into the same thing with both my mail providers using Lion with Mail 5.2. Most times I startup the application fresh, particularly after having powered down, it shows that dozens of messages are "incoming", however nothing shows up in my inbox. This is probably an internal sorting process, but may have something to do with the reversion of flag colors. Both providers use IMAP, one is AOL and the other is my school, which goes through MS Outlook Live online. I'm not too savvy about ISP, how might this affect the messages? I see I'm not supposed to ask more q

Comment: It's an unrelated topic, you won't get an answer without creating a new question.

Comment: @WilliamChenoweth: My issue is still unresolved. I suspect its a problem with my e-mail host: they don't seem to fully understand IMAP.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Gmail: Starred mails are represented as red flags in Apple Mail.